# перевод координат из МСК-39 зона 1 перевести в WGS-84

Tags: javascript, php, c#, c++

Дорогие форумчане, имеются x/y в МСК-39 зона 1 ,нужно получить latitude/longitude WGS-84. Перекопатил весь интернет, но никакого алгоритма перехода из мск 39 в WGS84 не нашел. Не понятно вообще в какой проекции/системе находятся координаты МСК-39. Пожалуйста помогите...

Comment: мск-39 это местная система координат калининградской области (загуглено https://mapbasic.ru/msk39)

Comment: я не геодезист и могу врать, но насколько я понимаю - формулы для пересчета из мск в wgs84 и обратно одни и те же для всех мск, у местных систем координат меняется точка привязки, развороты осей и коэффициент масштаба - 7 параметров

Comment: Пересчет координат (МСК, СК 63, СК 64, СК 47, WGS 84, ПЗ 90) онлайн https://geobridge.ru/proj#null